# How to use jQuery to compare each array number? and if less than input range number div tag will hide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have a question about Array in jQuery.

Below are my codes.

I have same class div tags, but different value in span tags.

I use input range bar to change value, if span tags value less then range bar value.

The correspondent div tags will be disappeared.

I could get same class array numbers, but can't compare.

How do I modify my code?

```js
$('#myRange').change(function() {
  let Price1 = parseInt($('#myRange').val());

  let Price2 = [];

  $('.price').each(function(index, el) {
    Price2[index] = parseInt(el.innerHTML);
  });

  if (Price2 > Price1) {
    $('.col').fadeOut();
    //console.log('yes');
  } else {
    $('.col').fadeIn();
    //console.log('no');
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" max="50" value="10" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange">


<div class="col">
  <span class="price">10</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <span class="price">20</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <span class="price">30</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <span class="price">40</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <span class="price">50</span>
</div>
```

Comment: First off, you're missing a closing `)` at the end of your script. I've updated the question to include this to avoid a syntax error. I've also included jQuery to your snippet.

Comment: You can't compare arrays with `>`

Comment: You also can't compare arrays with numbers and get any kind of meaningful result.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones This question isn't a useful addition to SO and will be closed/removed soon. I'm still helping op with their easy problem though. Not sure what your point is? That I should post an answer instead? Definitely not how this website works. OP missed that they have to iterate over the array they create. This is a basic logic error and requires more programming practice. It's not going to help future users.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, explaining the code changes to come up with a working solution as an official answer is definitely better than posting a link with no explanation. Also, "isn't a useful addition to SO and will be closed/removed soon" is your opinion (I'm not saying it's wrong), but please then vote to close the question. I could also see future users not knowing that they need to iterate over arrays to compare values, instead of being able to do `arr1 > arr2`. And if that's a duplicate already on the site, vote to close as duplicate :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey "educate me"? Feel free to tell me what I'm doing wrong in your opinion.

Comment: @ChrisG Using comments for something other than clarifying the question. Feel free to remind yourself what they're for from the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @HereticMonkey The way I see it, posting an answer is way worse here. The only way to keep SO usable instead of actively driving it completely into the ground *and* help OP is to solve their very basic problem off-site and link them there. A comment is a harmless and straightforward way to do this. Are you suggesting I should've posted an answer instead?

Comment: I'm suggesting you would vote to close the question if it is close-worthy. Not all questions have to be answered.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Just to clarify: you'd rather I don't help the OP with a fiddle comment because that's not how comments are used and downvote their question on top? Instead of what I did here? Just for the record. Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: @ChrisG I said nothing about how to use your up- or downvotes. I said to vote to close *if the question is close-worthy*. If the question is close-worthy, it should not be answered. If it is not close-worthy, then it can be answered with an answer, if desired. For the record. Not sure what's so radical about that.

Comment: I believe a middle-ground would've been beneficial to both the OP and SO. Write a full answer, but also vote to close the question. That way, the user gets the help they came here for, and if others agree to close the question, then your answer becomes moot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the value the user selected to the price value of every item (`.col`).

Here's a modified version of your example (specifically the JS code), with an added bonus of checking before the user does anything (and some code comments).

```js
  // check columns visibility on load
  checkPriceRange(parseInt($('#myRange').val()));

  // event listener for the range slider
  $('#myRange').change(function() {
    // get the user value
    let priceRange = parseInt($('#myRange').val());

    // call the comparison function, and update the UI accordingly
    checkPriceRange(priceRange);
  });

  function checkPriceRange(priceRange) {
    // iterate through every price item
    $('.price').each(function(index, el) {
      // get the parent of the price item, as that's what will be hidden
      let $column = $(this).closest('.col');
      // get the price of the price item
      let price = parseInt(el.innerHTML);
      // compare the price with what the user selected
      if (priceRange >= price) {
        $column.fadeIn();
      } else {
        $column.fadeOut();
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="50" value="10" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange">


  <div class="col">
    <span class="price">10</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <span class="price">20</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <span class="price">30</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <span class="price">40</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <span class="price">50</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this answer doesn't address your question regarding array comparison with jQuery, but in this case there is no reason to complicate things with an array. And since you're using `.each()` you can take advantage of $(this).

> ...the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.
> [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Here is a simplified working version:

```js
$('#myRange').change(function() {
  let Price = parseInt($('#myRange').val());
  $('.price').each(function(index, el) {
    if (parseInt(el.innerText) > Price) {
      $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" max="50" value="10" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange">


<div class="col">
  <span class="price">10</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <span class="price">20</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <span class="price">30</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <span class="price">40</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <span class="price">50</span>
</div>
```